# LaTeX Error: File subfigure.sty not found

Tags: errors, subfloats

I'm getting this error when compiling:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `subfigure.sty' not found.
```

Here is part of the relevant code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\setlength{\parindent}{1.4em}

\begin{document}    

\begin{figure}
    \subfigure[Scatter Plot]{
        \includegraphics[height=5cm]{graphs/scatter.pdf}
        \label{sub1}
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Does the error message mean I don't have the subfigure package? Isn't that standard?

I've installed texlive and have run `mktexlsr` as suggested [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=42108) but I'm still getting the error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Yep, that seems to be a missing pacakge error. However, instead of code snippets, it is always best to compose a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Thanks that will help.  However, the `subfigure` needs to be within `\begin{figure}..\end{figure}`, and you need `\end{document}`.  You can also remove the `listings` and `geometry` packages as they have no effect on the error here.  With those changes this compiles fine for me with TeXLive2011.

Comment: Also note that [the `subfigure` page](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/subfigure.html) states that the `subfigure` package is obsolete and that you should use `subfloat`.

Comment: `tlmgr update --self --all`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In case you installed TeX Live from the packages of a Linux distro: Most distros split less-used LaTeX-packages into separate (Linux-distro)-packages. From the link in your question I assume that you are running Arch Linux. In this case you need to install the [`texlive-latexextra` package](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/texlive-latexextra/) which contains subfigure.sty. If you are using a different distro, the necessary package might be named differently (e.g. `texlive-latex-extra` in Debian/Ubuntu).

Also, as Peter notes, the `subfigure` package is depreciated.

Comment: For reference, could you mention the `subcaption` package as an alternative for the OP.

Comment: Thanks for adding the package for Ubuntu. That happens to be what I'm using.

Comment: The package repositories in Ubuntu use TeXlive 2009, which is not the most recent version.

Comment: To find out which package a file belongs to on a Debian-derived system, use `apt-file search $FILENAME`. For example you could use `apt-file search /subfigure.sty` in this case.

Comment: In the end, it is much more convenient to use the net install and not to use your distro's packages https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=109427